# Getting the button into the top right corner inside the div box

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to get the [X] button into the top right corner of my custom css box.

Here's the result so far:

[image]

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

#wrapper {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#container {
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#inner1 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#titlebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 23px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#0A246A, endColorStr=#A6CAF0, GradientType=1);
  color: white;
  font: 13px arial, helvetica;
}

#button {
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="titlebar">Information Box</div>
    <div><input id="button" type="button" value="X"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just add `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;` to the CSS for your button.

```
 #button {
     line-height: 12px;
     width: 18px;
     font-size: 8pt;
     font-family: tahoma;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;
 }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e8eAb/)**

Comment: Interestingly without override it goes to top left of <h4> class. With override it goes to top right of page totally outside the <h4> class. I'm using Nov 29, 2021 Firefox though which I notice is different than current Chrome for line spacing today.

Answer (score 2):

To position the button to the right of the container but below the `#titlebar` you can use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

```
float: right;
```

to the button's CSS.

If you would like the button in the top right corner of the container (over the `#titlebar`) add the button before the `#titlebar`.

[image: place button in the top right corner]

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

#wrapper {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#container {
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#inner1 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#titlebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 23px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#0A246A, endColorStr=#A6CAF0, GradientType=1);
  color: white;
  font: 13px arial, helvetica;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#button {
  float: right;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

#button2 {
  float: right;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div><input id="button2" type="button" value="Y"></div>
    <div id="titlebar">Information Box</div>
    <div><input id="button" type="button" value="X"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And to center the text inside the button use:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

[image: place button in the top right corner of container]

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

#wrapper {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#container {
  background: #FFF;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#inner1 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#inner2 {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#titlebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 23px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#0A246A, endColorStr=#A6CAF0, GradientType=1);
  color: white;
  font: 13px arial, helvetica;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#button {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

#button2 {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div><input id="button2" type="button" value="Y"></div>
    <div id="titlebar">Information Box</div>
    <div><input id="button" type="button" value="X"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```